# Can't configure Yesod correctly for API

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm wishing to build an API using Haskell and Yesod.

However I'm facing some problems.

I've used `stack` to set up a new Haskell project with the `yesod-sqlite` template, went ahead and deleted the default Handlers, also removed anywhere they're mentioned in both `Application.hs` and my cabal file, but, unforunately they are also mentioned in `Foundation.hs` in a lot of places. for some reason the handlers are **very** embedded into Yesod, which I find strange.

I don't need any static content or any templates or anything that results in HTML.
I just want to return JSON, so I'm wondering if there's a way to ditch `Foundation.hs` safely, as it looks like it's responsible for the templating, or atleast a way to safely remove Handlers and disable the forced templating.

Comment: Yeaod's scaffolding s are a big beast and somehow the strength of it. If you are stripping everything you'll probably be better starting​ from scratch and only use the scaffolding as reference.

Comment: If you don't need anything of the scaffolded site, then don't use the scaffolded site instead of trying to strip everything you don't need away from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need any Session feature or must use Yesod. warp & wai-route & persistent can be a choice. Later you can easy go back to Yesod, once you get the idea, the mechanism behind is close. If you must use Yesod, erase the instance declaration you don't want in the Foundation.hs

Comment: While this doesn't really answer the question I feel like it's the most sane option to just go with warp, wai-route and persistent, hence why I accept it as the answer.